# Can I use an external AC/DC power supply to power 4 SATA HDD?

Tags: power-supply, sata, hard-drive

I would like to power 4 SATA HDD enclosed in [this bay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00V5JHOXQ) with an external AC/DC power supply [like this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/RID-85A/7706001).

I am looking at the IronWolf 3TB ST3000VN007 ([data sheet](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/ironwolf-12tb-DS1904-17-2011US-en_US.pdf), and [user manual](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/ironwolf/en-us/docs/100807039k.pdf)) whose power specs are:

[image: IronWolf 3TB power specs]

And from the manual:

> **2.6 Power specifications**
> The drive receives DC power (+5V or +12V) through a native SATA power connector.

As far as I understand, all I would need is to wire up the power supply to a [four pin Molex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector#Disk_drive), plug that into a [four pin Molex to 15 pin SATA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IJGL8PW) connector, and finally power up the enclosure.

As far as I understand, this power supply carries both a 5v, and a 12v line with respectively 8A and 4A, and that all SATA HDD need.

Is this bad? Am I going to see smoke coming out? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: A generic power supply may or may not have good enough voltage/load regulation.  There's a good chance it would work.  You haven't mentioned the power consumption per SATA drive which would be relevant.  I'd check what kind of power supplies are normally used with that kind of rack mount bay.

Comment: For 2.5" SATA drives, are you sure you need +12V?   5V only is usual <https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/barracuda-2-5-DS1907-3-2005US-en_US.pdf>

Comment: some drives may want 3.3V

Comment: @KH what would be a good range given the above power requirements?

Comment: @Whit3rd you are right, some 2.5" SATA drives are good without the separate cable, but some models still need the power, in my case I am using 3.5", and I've updated the post with their power specs.

Comment: @Jasen correct, although in my case the drives I am using don't need it.

Comment: For completeness, I am basing my information on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_connectors), which has a good explainer on the different voltages and their uses.

Comment: Buy the proper drive enclosure that has a power supply.

Comment: How are you intending to connect four SATA drives to a computer if they are housed externally to that computer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton my intention isn't to connect them to a computer, but to a raspberry pi cm4 via a pic express sata card, and all of that stuff is already working.

Comment: @Moab the bay I posted in my question, is what I consider "proper" for my use case: cheap and small. The power+case is under 100$, and the case is as big as it can be.
Are there other enclosures I should consider under 100$ or around that price?

Comment: @holofermes Does "all of that stuff is already working" mean that you have it all set up and working? If so, what PSU are you currently using and why do you think a different one could be a problem?

Comment: @holofermes Perhaps the one thing you need to know is that the two parts must have a common ground: the 0 V of the drives' PSU needs to be connected to the 0 V of the RPi CM. If you are powering them from some strangely wired electrical mains which is not properly earthed then you should expect problems.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't set up the 4 HDD in the case, but I have connected two each with its own generic external power adapter, like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Warmstor-Adapter-Computer-Connector-Converter/dp/B076WZ1N4K). So you are saying that as long as the RPi CM, and the Meanwell power supply are plugged in the same outlet, I should be good?

Comment: @holofermes Make sure that all the connections are made *before* switching on the mains. Switch mode power supplies can "float" at about half of mains voltage, so if their ground lines (0 V) are connected together then they will float to the same voltage at the same time. If you connect them at some time after they are switched on, there could be a spark as they equalize.